# NodeJS - Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I already "Googled it" and found many similar answers here. This is my exact error.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 43, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 5.19 KiB, done.
Total 43 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:vidperdiem.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:vidperdiem.git'
```

Yes I did follow the Heroku guide (which said to NPM install) and verified that my repo on Heroku was a remote

[image: npm install]

and these are my files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vidperdiem",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "stylus": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node app.js
```

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.render('about', {
    title: 'About'
  });
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.render('contact', {
    title: 'Contact'
  });
});

app.get('/privacy', function(req, res){
  res.render('privacy', {
    title: 'Privacy'
  });
});

app.get('/terms', function(req, res){
  res.render('terms', {
    title: 'Terms'
  });
});

app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Quick guess: make sure both `Procfile` and `package.json` are indeed tracked by git

Comment: @NitzanShaked i used the default `.gitignore` from Github, so that was not the problem. the problem was that I created the repo on Github and then cloned locally, and then in that file, I THEN created the nodejs app. so I was able to push changed to github as my origin, but with heroku I was not in the root. so i copied the files out of the app folder and brought them into the main folder. Should I delete my question or answer with the lesson learned?

Comment: Answer with lesson learned. You can even accept your own answer. It's in rhe SO faq. Way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running into this challenge like many people did, make sure that you have the basics covered. In my case I needed to be in the root when pushing to Heroku. As obvious as this sounds let me explain how this happened so that you can avoid this frustration.

I had originally created the repo on Github, then cloned it locally. Then in the terminal I entered the project which had the `README.md` and `.gitignore` that I initialized it with on github.

At that point I created the nodejs app and named it "app".

Then I created an app on Heroku (through the site because it is easier to name it instead of getting a long app name) that happens when you do `heroku create`.

I went back into the terminal and added heroku as the remote with `heroku git:remote -a appname` (where "appname" is the name of your repo).

The problem here is that if you are tracking the app on Heroku as well, this will cause it to be a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) on github.

So that is why I added heroku as the remote from the same place where github tracks changes.

Bottomline: 
I copied the files out of the "app" folder and placed it back into the root.

[image]

Make sure that the following files are in your root
`app.js`
`package.json`
`Procfile`

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled across this answer when trying to figure a similar issue out for myself.

In my instance, I'm moving from a non-Heroku deployment to a Heroku deployment. So the Herkou instance is running on a new (local) git branch I've setup, and thus not master.

The answer, once I worked it out, is obvious. Rather than calling `git push heroku master`, I had to run  `git push heroku mylocalbranch:master`, as I was trying to push the old, non-heroku deployment, which obviously isn't going to work :)